# Is there a way to write to a file in C with data from another function?

Tags: arrays, c, function, file

I've been developing a rendition of the Oware Abapa game in C, and was wondering if there is a way for me to take data from one function and write it on a save file with that information.

My two functions are `show()` and `saveFile()`, and are presented as follows

```c
void show( int player, t_Pit p[], t_Pit s[], int win ) {
    int a = player, o = !a; // 'a'ctive & 'o'pponent

    int x = a ? 0 : 6;
    int y = a ? 6 : 0;
    char *str = win ? "Wins the game\n\n" : "Select pit (1-6)\nSave board state (0): ";
    printf(
            "\n"
            "----+-----player%d-----+\n"
            "%2d  |%2d|%2d|%2d|%2d|%2d|%2d|\n"
            "----+-----------------+\n"
            "%2d  |%2d|%2d|%2d|%2d|%2d|%2d|\n"
            "----+-----player%d-----+\t"

            "\nPlayer %d %s",
            o,  s[o], p[y+5], p[y+4], p[y+3], p[y+2], p[y+1], p[y+0], // NB: custom indexing
            s[a], p[x+0], p[x+1], p[x+2], p[x+3], p[x+4], p[x+5], a,
            a, str
    );
}

void saveFile(const t_Pit pit[], int nPit) {
    char fName[26];
    printf("Input a name for the save file:");scanf("%s", &fName);
    FILE *save = fopen(fName, "w");
    if (save == NULL) {
        perror("Error opening file for writing");
        return;
    }

    fprintf(save, "deposit1\n");
    fprintf(save, "info about player 1's pits");
    
    fprintf(save, "\ndeposit0\n");
    fprintf(save, "info about player 0's pits");
    
    fclose(save);printf("file '%s' saved.", fName);

}
```

Please note that the `fprintf()` statements should write as is in `show()`, I'm just unsure of how I could code such.
Furthermore, all user input is being done in the `main()` function, along with the code to progress in the game itself

Comment: What is it you are unsure about?  Just copy the `printf` line from above, change it to `fprintf` and add `save` as parameter 1.

Comment: @DavidJones what about the variables that dont translate from ```show()``` to ```saveState()```?

Comment: I'd take your existing `show()` function and rename it and modify it to take an extra `FILE *fp` argument (e.g. it becomes `void fshow(FILE *fp, int player, t_Pit p[], t_Pit s[], int win)`), and modify the the `printf(…)` to `fprintf(fp, …)`.  Then I'd create a function `show()` with the signature above and the body would become `fshow(stdout, …)` — simply passing `stdout` as the file stream.  Then your `saveFile()` calls `fshow(save, …)` with the appropriate argument list.  This minimizes the maintenance overhead. Copying the (complex) `printf()` in the `show()` function is a major liability.